# Why does ExpandoObject not work as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Currently, not even the simplest examples of using the 'ExpandoObject' work on my machine.

Both

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Value = 10;
var action = new Action<string>((line) => Console.WriteLine(line));
obj.WriteNow = action;
obj.WriteNow(obj.Value.ToString());
```

[(from this website)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62839/Adventures-with-C-4-0-dynamic-ExpandoObject-Elasti) and

```
dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
sampleObject.test = "Dynamic Property";
Console.WriteLine(sampleObject.test);
```

[(from the MSDN examples)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) fail with a RuntimeBinderException. I presume I've misconfigured something, but I am at a loss about what it might be.

I am using .NET v4.0.30319 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Premium. Please ask for anything else you might need to know. =)

Comment: Wild. What kind of project is that - console?

Comment: Yes, it is.. and I just tried to create a new, empty console application, and it works there! I should stop reusing a single console application for all my hacking, it seems. Thanks =)

Comment: Ah, and it works outside of the debugger, too.. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the hidden "SolutionName.suo" file in the solution directory fixed this problem for me.

I still have no clue why it occured, though.

**Edit:** 
Andras Zoltan, who deleted his answer, guessed correctly. I have had "Break on all Exceptions" enabled and was being stupid. =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that `Console.WriteLine` has too many overloads and so the dynamic part cannot be figured out correctly.
Put the output into a typed variable before or just cast it.
e.g.

```
dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
sampleObject.test = "Dynamic Property";
Console.WriteLine((string)sampleObject.test);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's not it, though. The exact same code works if used in another project, and even if running without a debugger.

Comment: But the typecast to string does fix the problem though.

Comment: It does not in my project, sorry.